# Switch to Neon Mode Raspberry Pi Cluster

Tags: gcc, assembly, raspberry-pi, arm, neon

I'm getting the following error message when compiling a .S assembly file with

> gcc -o output input.S

Error message:

> Error: selected processor does not support `veor.f64 d2,d2' in ARM mode

How can i switch to the correct mode?

Comment: @fuz I don't understand how somebody can proclaim such nonsense and get their comment upvoted. The ARMv7 in the RPi2 does absolutely have a NEON unit.

Comment: @EOF Huch?  I'm very sorry.  I appear to be misinformed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's one of the later Pi models with an ARMv7 core, not the first version which was ARM11 (ARMv6), then you need to add `-mfpu=NEON`.